# CSS and HTML inconsistent when declaring multiple classes

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS "seriously" for the first time, but I've found that the way you deal with multiple CSS classes in CSS and HTML quite inconsistent.

For example, I learned that if I want to declare multiple CSS classes with a common style applied to them, I write:

```
.style1, .style2, .style3 {
   color: red;
}
```

Then, if I want to declare an HTML tag that has multiple classes applied to it, I write:

```
<div class="style1 style2 style3"></div>
```

And I'm asking why? From my personal point of view it would be more consistent if both could be declared by using a comma to separate each class, or if both could be declared using a space; after all IMHO we're still talking about multiple classes, in both CSS and HTML. I think that it would make more sense if I could write this to declare a `div` with multiple classes applied:

```
<div class="style1, style2, style3"></div>
```

Am I'm missing something important? Could you explain me if there's a valid reason behind these two different syntaxes?

Comment: There are several other inconsistencies you'll discover as you learn HTML and CSS. Most of them can be attributed to the fairly inconsistent way both technologies grew: Every browser vendor out there added this and that without conforming to a standard. Sometimes for good reason (lack of a standard), sometimes not. It will get (a lot) worse when you start learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I presume you meant to say `.style1 .style2 .style3` in your CSS example, otherwise you're referring to tag names.)

In CSS, `.style1 .style2` means something completely different from `.style1, .style2`: the first only applies an element to which has both style1 and style2 classes, the second applies to both style1 and style2 individually. That distinction is vital (don't forget the C in CSS means "cascading"), so there shouldn't be a way of eliminating the need for the comma.

Now, as to why you can't use commas in the HTML element, you may well have a point: unfortunately it's too late to do anything about it.

Comment: Sorry, You're right.. I mispelled them. BTW Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Actually `.style1 .style2` would only match elements with style2 class that are nested inside elements with style1.

Comment: And it's `.style1.style2` that applies to element with both classes.